# Python Script executed from VBA not writting on excel

Tags: python, excel, vba, openpyxl

I'm using a Macro on Excel to run a python script. This Script reads some data from excel, makes some calculus and inserts the result in the same Excel.
When I run the python Script in cmd from windows, there is no problem.
However, when running the script from VBA it makes nothing.

This is the Python Script that I'm using:

```
from openpyxl import Workbook
from openpyxl import load_workbook

filesheet = input("ingrese nombre del archivo (extensión excel): ")
wb=Workbook()

wb = load_workbook(filesheet, data_only = True, keep_vba= True)
ws = wb["ESTADOS"]
ww = wb["SEÑALES"]

binario = str(ws["D27"].value)
print(binario)
hexa = hex(int(binario,2))
print(hexa)

filas = int(ww.max_row)

for x in range(2,filas+1):
    celda = str(ww.cell(row = x, column = 2).value)
    if celda == str("None") and hexa != 0:
        print(hexa)
        ww.cell(row = x, column=2).value = hexa
        hexa=0
```

And this is the VBA code that I'm using:

```
Sub link_python()

Dim objShell As Object
Dim PythonExe As String
Dim PythonScript As Variant

Set objShell = VBA.CreateObject("Wscript.shell")
         
    'Provide the file path to the Python Exe
    PythonExe = """C:\Users\z004nxje\python.exe"""
         
    'Provide the file path to the Python script
    PythonScript = "C:\Users\z004nxje\SITRA\Script.py"
         
    'Run the Python script
    objShell.Run PythonExe & " " & PythonScript
    Application.Goto Reference:="link_python"



End Sub
```

Anyone knows why it isn't writing on the Excel cells?
Thanks

Comment: Are you inputting the absolute filename name including the path ?

Comment: Hi, yes I've tried to include the absolute path but it doesn't write the result on excel.

Comment: try to have two excel files, one for executing Python and pass data to it, and two an excel file to store output data, because if you want to store it in the same file it will give you an error (unauthorised)

Comment: If possible, I would need to do it in the same file. There is any other python library that allows that?

Comment: Is that the complete python script ? Is there not a `wb.save(filesheet)` ?

Comment: I added but still not working